# Local Storage for Multiligual App on appery.io

Tags: javascript, android

This is my first App page I am trying to create. I am using appery.io platform. I am trying to create one page that has a menu of two options (languages) such that, when the user choses the langauge (German, English), the header will show the langauge as follow:
German> Deutsch
English=> English

My page contains two componenets:

- Caption/header: has the text "header"
- Select menu: has two options (English, German).

I have done the following:

1. I created two translation.json files for both langauges and inserted the following :

   de-DE: { "header":"Deutsch"}
   en-EN: { "header":"English" }
2. I have created four events for selectMenu component as follow:
   a.  selectMenu > click > set local storage variable:

   - variable name: language
   - value: var language = Appery("mobileselectmenu_10").find(":selected").text();

   b. selectMenu > click > set local storage variable:

   - variable name: language
   - value: var language = Appery("mobileselectmenu_10").find(":selected").text();

   c. selectMenu > change value > run java script:

   - localStorage.getItem("language");

   var option = {lng: language, resGetPath: 'locales/_lng/ns.json', fallbackLng: 'en-US'};    //Pass the initialization language, 
   //set the translation files path and fallback language 
   $.i18n.init(option, function(t) { 
   $(document).i18n(); //Once the translations are loaded translate the whole document 
   });

   d. selectMenu > change value run java script:

   - localStorage.getItem("language");
   - var option = {lng: language, resGetPath: 'locales/_lng/ns.json', fallbackLng: 'en-US'}; //Pass the initialization language, 
     //set the translation files path and fallback language 
     $.i18n.init(option, function(t) { 
     $(document).i18n(); //Once the translations are loaded translate the whole document 
     });

When I test the App, I get the following error in the console:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: German jquery-1.9.1.js:4421 
Sizzle.error jquery-1.9.1.js:4421 
Sizzle.selectors.filter.PSEUDO jquery-1.9.1.js:4776 
matcherFromTokens jquery-1.9.1.js:5294 
Sizzle.compile jquery-1.9.1.js:5435 
select jquery-1.9.1.js:5513 
Sizzle jquery-1.9.1.js:3998 
$.find jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js:220 
jQuery.fn.extend.find jquery-1.9.1.js:5576 
$.off.on.change startScreen.js:138 
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074 
elemData.handle jquery-1.9.1.js:2750 
jQuery.event.trigger jquery-1.9.1.js:2986 
(anonymous function) jquery-1.9.1.js:3677 
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.9.1.js:648 
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.9.1.js:270 
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery-1.9.1.js:3676 
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js:11295 
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074 
elemData.handle

I know I might be missing something so trivial, but my knowledge in App development is faily limited. I deeply appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem: `find(":selected")`, as it seems to be a "pseudo"-element used with no specific context.

Try doing something like eg. `find("option:selected")` or `find(".my_class:selected")`

Reference:
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately, I am getting the same error

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that. However, more code to look at would be nice. Or a fiddle. Hard to say what the problem is based just on what you wrote.